# How can i create templates for four plots in a single panel using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written script for four single plot using python.Also for some reason i want to combine all four into a single panel.I want to create one template.
How can create templates for to display four plots in a single panel using python?

```
import cdms2,vcs,cdutil,cdtime,os,sys,time
f=cdms2.open('/home/alagu/Desktop/data/1xco2.cam2.h0.0001-01.nc')
data=f('Z3')    
v=vcs.init()
v.plot(data)
v.gs('Z3.jpg',device='jpeg', orientation='p')
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/index.htm).

- Create an empty image that is as least twice as wide and high as the largest plot created by vcs.
- Then load the images that vcs produces and paste them into the empty image.
- Write the new image to disk.

Like this:

```
from PIL import Image

srcs = []
srcs.append(Image.open('Z1.jpg'))
srcs.append(Image.open('Z2.jpg'))
srcs.append(Image.open('Z3.jpg'))
srcs.append(Image.open('Z4.jpg'))

xoffs = max([i.size[0] for i in srcs])
yoffs = max([i.size[0] for i in srcs])

combined = Image.new('RGBA', (2*xoffs, 2*yoffs))

combined.paste(srcs[0], (0,0))
combined.paste(srcs[1], (xoffs,0))
combined.paste(srcs[2], (0,yoffs))
combined.paste(srcs[3], (xoffs,yoffs))

combined.write('combined.jpg')
```